# Visual Studio 2010 - Is there a standard width before wrapping your lines (comments)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, comments

Basically, is there any "standard" width to go by before wrapping your lines for readability? I know this *could be* subjective, but I'm hoping there is an actual design guideline for character width before wrapping your lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be a standard of [80 characters](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/05/31/is-the-80-character-line-limit-still-relevant/) - this was because terminals could only show that much.

These days, with wide screens (and multiple screens), there isn't such a thing.

You need to talk to your team mates, see what everyone is comfortable with and stick with that.

Comment: Take the one who works with the lowest resolution and see how many chars fits in his screen.

Comment: The old new standard: what fits in a SO code block with invoking the horizontal scrollbar.  81 characters.  +1 for progress.